# Webview not loading html or javascript Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview, http-get

I am retrieving the whole html and javascript of a page I get from an HttpGet. I can successfully get the Html and the Javascript. When I try and load it into the web view, the web view gives me "Page not available" and shows the html and javascript that was to be loaded in a really weird format with percentages in between the elements. I am positive the html and javascript is being downloaded and in the shape of an Html page. I have also enabled javascript in the web view. What could be causing such a problem? Code:

```
public void parseDoc() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
            sting.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, true);
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "https://secure.groupfusion.net/processlogin.php");
            String HTML = "";
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        3);
                nameValuePairs
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "referral_page",
                                "/modules/gradebook/ui/gradebook.phtml?type=student_view&jli=t&jli=t&jli=t&jli=t&jli=t&jli=t&printable=FALSE&portrait_or_landscape=portrait"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("currDomain",
                        "beardenhs.knoxschools.org"));
                nameValuePairs
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
                nameValuePairs
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HTML = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HTML);
                Element link = doc.select("a").first();
                linkHref = link.attr("href");

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                try {
                    request.setURI(new URI(linkHref));

                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                response = httpclient.execute(request);

                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
                in.close();
                HTML = str.toString();
                sting.loadData(HTML, "text/html", null);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

        }
    }).start();

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to load WebView using following method

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlString,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
```