# Android WebView injected element do not always appear

Tags: jquery, android, html, web-applications

I am working on a webapp with Android. Here is my problem:

After I append some HTML to the DOM by JQuery's `append` function:

```
$sectionList.append(options.$html);
```

The new elements were shown on the page in some occasions, but sometimes not! I've made sure the elements were appended to the DOM, they just don't always appear.

Somebody encountered the same problem?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Aaron, it's typical to show your code in the question.

Comment: this may help u see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514505/webview-not-loading-html-or-javascript-android

Comment: please show your code in this Question. then we can help your

Comment: my code just like this: $sectionList.append(options.$html);

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem - however for me it is more device specific. If the updates occur on an Android phone (e.g. SGS3) then it is absolutely fine. The same application, when put on an Android tablet (e.g. Asus Transformer Prime), fails to update the text cell. I'm using jquery to update DIVs through the $("#divname").html("new text"); method...